# How to convert an int to ASCII char C++

Tags: c++, hex, type-conversion, ascii, arrays

I have to convert an int to an ASCII string.
Basically, i want this :

```
    int iTest = 128;
    char ca[3];
??? --> **SOLUTION :** sprintf(ca,"%d",iTest);
```

and the result :

```
 ca[0] = 0x31;--> Hexcode of '1'
 ca[1] = 0x32;
 ca[2] = 0x38;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

...

int iTest = 128;

string ca = to_string(iTest);

for (int i = 0; i < ca.size(); i++)
{
    cout << hex << "0x" << (int) ca[i] << endl;
}
```

Result:

```
0x31
0x32
0x38
```

Comment: sprintf(ca,"%d",iTest);
is also working well, thanks everybody :D

Comment: Yes, but using C++ it's recommended to use type-safe methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
for each digit
    ca[ i ] = digit + '0';
```

Notes:

- note the different lengths of the number
- allocate `ca` dynamically, based on the "length" of the number (the number of digits)
- iterating over each digit can be done by using `%` and `/` operators for modulo and division.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo and division operators to get each digit, then print each digit adding `'0'`.